# Cannot save database changes to MySQL docker image

Tags: mysql, docker

I am attempting to make a change to a MySQL docker instance of a database and save this as an image to use at later point. I can spawn the MySQL database, make changes to it, but when I ***COMMIT*** the container instance, then the database changes are not saved. If I spawn a container from the image, it still has the old changes.

These are the steps that I executed :

1. I first spawn a MySQL instance like so:

> ```
> docker run -d -p 6033:3306 --name=test1 --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root" --env="MYSQL_PASSWORD=root" --env="MYSQL_DATABASE=myDB" mysql
> ```

2. Next I pull in my SCHEMA.sql which creates some new tables like so :

> ```
> docker exec -i test1 mysql -uroot -proot myDB < SCHEMA.sql
> ```

3. Next I inspect my instance to see if the new tables are there.

> ```
> docker exec -it test1 bash
> mysql -uroot -proot
> show databases;
> use myDB;
> show tables;
> ```

My new tables are there!!

My plan now is to take an image of this and recreate another container instance.

4. I commit

> ```
> docker commit test1
> ```

5. I tag the image

> ```
> docker tag e2d6f1b70bbe new_image:1.1
> ```

6. Now I run :

> ```
> docker run -d -p 3401:3306 --name test2 new_image:1.1
> ```

7. Next I Inspect to see if tables are there

> ```
> docker exec -it test2 bash
> mysql -uroot -proot
> show databases;
> use myDB;
> show tables;
> ```

My tables are NOT there!! (and that makes me sad :´( )

Comment: The standard Docker Hub database images are built in a way that you can't commit an image with data (their data is always in a volume and commit doesn't preserve volumes).  `docker commit` is rarely a best practice in any case; without a recipe to rebuild the image (the Dockerfile) it leads to images that can't be recreated, which means you can't get security updates and other bug fixes in the underlying software.

Comment: so it is preferable to use a DockerFile to define a particular state of the database you are in? Eg. Pull MySQL, play in schema and test data... all in DockerFile

Comment: It's always preferable to use a Dockerfile to committing an image; but the standard database images are built in a way that neither will actually contain persisted data.